# dynamically changing classes in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, tailwind-css

I am going through this little [tutorial](https://tailwindcss.com/course/toggling-the-navbar-links-on-mobile/) the guy is using Vue and I have never dynamically changed classes in React before.  I am trying to replicate this:

```
    <div :class="isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'" class="px-2 pt-2 pb-4">
      <a href="#" class="block px-2 py-1 text-white font-semibold rounded hover:bg-gray-800">List your property</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-2 py-1 text-white font-semibold rounded hover:bg-gray-800">Trips</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-2 py-1 text-white font-semibold rounded hover:bg-gray-800">Messages</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

This is the component I am trying to achieve it on.

```
const Nav = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query {
            site {
                siteMetadata {
                    title
                    author
                    social
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    return (
        <header className="bg-gray-900">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between px-4 py-3 mb-4s">
                <div>
                    <h1 className="mb-0 text-2xl">
                        <Link to="/">
                            {data.site.siteMetadata.social}
                        </Link>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" className="block text-gray-500 hover:text-white focus:text-white focus:outline-none">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
                    </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="px-2 pt-2 pb-4">
                <Link
                    className="block px-2 py-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-800"
                    activeClassName=""
                >
                    Open Source
                </Link>
                <Link
                    className="mt-1 block px-2 py-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-800"
                    activeClassName=""
                    to="/posts"
                >
                    Posts
                </Link>
                <Link
                    className="mt-1 block px-2 py-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-800"
                    activeClassName=""
                    to="/contact"
                >
                    Contact
                </Link>
            </div>

        </header>
    )
}
```

I have tried a few things but as I am pretty new to react and new to the way things are done I am little lost.

any pointers would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple as using a simple ternary. For example, you want to toggle between 
`className` 'red' and 'green'  based on the value of variable `isOpen`,

```js
// assume some variable isOpen is a boolean value which will be set dynamically

const myClassName = isOpen ? 'green' : 'red';

// in your component the set the className prop to the className you created
return (
  <div className={myClassName}>
    my dynamic element
  </div>
)
```

You can also do that in one line

```js
// in your component

return (
  <div className={isOpen ? 'green' : 'red'}>
   my dynamic element
  </div>
)
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x0wc5?file=/App.js) example.

Also, let's say you want an existing CSS class name to merge with another className depending on the value of a variable.

```js
// let's say you want to add 'color-green' depending on variable isOpen with 
// an existing class of 'flex-container'

const existingCls = 'flex-container'

const myClassName = isOpen ? `${existingCls} color-green` : existingCls
```